# Como resolver TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Cliente

Tags: python, json

Estou tentando criar um códiggo que seria como um sistema de barbearia, criei uma classe Cliente e algumas funções dentro dela incluindo uma função para gravar os dados em um Json.
Porém ao tentar executar a função Salvar, exepcificamente em `"Funcionario": self.identification,"horario": horariosList[horarioEscolha]`  para salvar  em um Json ocorre o seguingte erro: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Cliente

Como posso resolver este problema?

```py
import json

caminho_arquivo = 'agenda.json'

pessoa = [
{
  "id": 0,
  "nome": "Raquel Matos",
  "funcao": "corte",
  "horarios": [
    "manha", "tarde", "noite"
  ],
  "preco": 1.8
},
{
  "id": 1,
  "nome": "Kessy Alves",
  "funcao": "corte",
  "horarios": [
    "manha", "tarde", "noite"
  ],
  "preco": 1.8
}
]


for horas in pessoa:
    horariosList = (horas['horarios'])
    horariosList1 = (horas['horarios'])
    horariosList2 = (horas['horarios'])


print(horariosList)


#horariosList = ["manha", "tarde", "noite"]


class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, nome= 'not defined', telefone= 'not defined', identification  = 'not defined'):
        self.nome = nome
        # self.funcao = funcao
        # self.horarios = horarios
        self.telefone = telefone
        self.identification = identification


    def Menu_Principal(self):
        print("=-==-=-==-=-==-=-==-=-==-=-==-=")
        print(f"[ {agendar} ] AGENDAR")
        print(f"[ {n2} ] FINANCEIRO")

    def Cliente(self):
        print("=-==-=-==-=-==-=-==-=-==-=-==-=")
        print('CADASTRAR CLIENTE ')

    def HorarioFuncionarios(self):
        id2 = int(self.identification)
        ide = 0 #variavel enumera funcionarios
        for pessoas in pessoa:
            print(f"{ide} - {pessoas['nome']}")
            ide += 1
            #print(list(enumerate(nomesP, 0)))
        for pessoas2 in pessoa:
            print("FUNCIONARIO ESCOLHIDO")
            print(pessoa[id2]['nome'])

    def salvar(self):
        # p1= self.nome
        # p2=self.telefone
        # info = [vars(p1),  vars(p2)]
        info = {'nome': self.nome, 'telefone': self.telefone}
        infoFinal = [
            {
                "name": self.nome,
                "tel": self.telefone,
                "Funcionario": self.identification,
                "horario": horariosList[horarioEscolha]
            }]
        print(info)

        dados = info
        with open(caminho_arquivo, 'w', encoding='utf8') as arquivo:
            json.dump(infoFinal, arquivo, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
        return dados
        Cliente.append(info)
agendar = 1
n2 = 2


while True:
    print('ESCOLHA UMA OPÇÃO')
    print(f"[ {agendar} ] Agendar")
    print(f"[ {n2} ] Financeiro")
    opcao = int(input("Informe uma opção? "))
    if opcao == 1:
        nom = Cliente(nome=input('NOME: '), telefone=input('TELEFONE: '))
        nom2 = Cliente(identification=input('Digite o id do funcionario'))
        print(nom2.identification)

        print('horario funcionario***')

        nom2.HorarioFuncionarios()
        print("ESCOLHA UM HORARIO")
        print(list(enumerate(horariosList, 0)))

        horarioEscolha = Cliente(identification=int(input("SELECIONE UM HORARIO PELO ID INDICADO ")))
        if horarioEscolha == 1:
            print(f"HORARIO ESCOLHIDO {horariosList[horarioEscolha]}")
            horariosEscolhido= horariosList[horarioEscolha]

            horariosList.pop(horarioEscolha)
            print("Horarios Disponiveis")
            print(horariosList)


        else:
            print("invalido")

        nom.salvar()

        print(f'++++++++++++++++\n O usuario {nom.nome},\n com o numero de telefone {nom.telefone}\n selecionou o profissional {nom2.identification} no periodo da ')

    elif opcao == 2:
        print('opcao 2')
    else:
        print('opção não existe')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

É porque "horarioEscolha" é uma instancia de Client e não um inteiro, pela sua lógica ai é só fazer:

```py
horariosList[horarioEscolha.identification]
```

que vai funcionar. Mas aconselho que reveja sua classe e principalmente sua função que inputa dados pois tá bem confusa e vai gerar mais bugs futuros.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).